# Why does this shell script output 7.9290 when I input 7.9285?

Tags: shell

```
    read x
x="${x}+0.0005"
echo "scale = 3; $x" | bc
```

I don't know why "scale = 3 " doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention which shell you use: zsh, bash, csh, ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because division uses the scale variable, but not addition, subtraction, or multiplication.

So to get the effect of scale over here, divide it by `1`;

```
echo "scale = 3; ($x)/1" | bc
```